# Using Windows Store controls in a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

We are looking at creating a new mobile application which will run on tablets using full Windows 8. We would like to be able to use full SQL for our data storage (which can be accessed easily using Windows Forms apps), but also retain the nice controls and touch friendliness provided by Windows Store apps (e.g. the LayoutAwarePage and the Windows 8 XAML controls).

We were looking at a way to use the Windows Store libraries within a Windows Forms application (as mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj856306.aspx#consuming_standard_windows_runtime_types), but have had no joy beyond adding the reference to a solution.

Does anyone know how to add a LayoutAwarePage to a Windows Forms application? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to look like a windows 8 app try having a look at MahApps

http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/

Its pretty easy to use and look pretty good, this is for wpf though not winforms

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response here; but as it said in the question,. we are aiming for the touch-friendliness, not specifically the look, so WPF doesn't really do what we need.